# List all files, recursively, in Android Dropbox API

Tags: android, file, dropbox, dropbox-api

How can I list **all files, recursively** in DropBox folder?
I tried code below but returns no result:

```
result = dbxClient.files().search("", "*");
```

And this returns files in path, not subfolders:

```
result = dbxClient.files().listFolder(path);
```

Comment: Note that [`search`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#search-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) doesn't support a `"*"` wildcard like that. You should use the list folder functionality for this anyway though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a [`ListFolderBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/ListFolderBuilder.html) from [`listFolderBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolderBuilder-java.lang.String-) and use the [`withRecursive`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/ListFolderBuilder.html#withRecursive-java.lang.Boolean-) option to list out sub-items as well.

Be sure to check [`ListFolderResult.hasMore`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/ListFolderResult.html#hasMore) to see if you should call back to [`listFolderContinue`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolderContinue-java.lang.String-) to get more results though.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this link, navigate to inner class 'FolderScanTask'. It contains working code for Android:
https://github.com/ControlX/Android-Dropbox-UploadImage-To-SpecificFolder-By-FolderSelection/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/controlx/dbxdemo/MainActivity.java

This is work in progress, here I'm just making an ArrayList for parent folders, has more logic as suggested by Greg is already there you just need to fill in that.

Code Snippet for the same:

```
        String path = "";
        DbxClientV2 dbxClient = DropboxClient.getClient(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        TreeMap<String, Metadata> children = new TreeMap<String, Metadata>();

        try {
            try {
                result = dbxClient.files()
                        .listFolder(path);
            } catch (ListFolderErrorException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            List<Metadata> list = result.getEntries();
            cs = new CharSequence[list.size()];
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add("/");
            while (true) {
                int i = 0;
                for (Metadata md : result.getEntries()) {
                    if (md instanceof DeletedMetadata) {
                        children.remove(md.getPathLower());
                    } else {
                        String fileOrFolder = md.getPathLower();
                        children.put(fileOrFolder, md);
                        if(!fileOrFolder.contains("."))
                            arrayList.add(fileOrFolder);
                    }
                    i++;
                }

                if (!result.getHasMore()) break;

                try {
                    result = dbxClient.files()
                            .listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());
                } catch (ListFolderContinueErrorException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (DbxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Here ArrayList is just for my use wherein I'm just making a list of only folders. 
So, modify accordingly.**